# passing arguments to API created by flask in python

Tags: python, api, flask, flask-restful, heroku-api

I am a complete newbie to API and python. actually, after getting disappointed to find a free host supporting plumber in R I decided to try it by python. The simple problem is that I have a simple function which takes two numeric arguments and using a given CSV file do some calculations and returns a number (I have simply made this in R by the plumber in localhost). now for a test in python have written below code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "hello world!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

well, this correctly works. but when I try to make a function to take arguments like this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello(a):
    return a + 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I get this page which says I have not passed the arguments.

[image]

my main question is that how I can pass the arguments? (in API created by R plumber, for example, I call it like: `localhost/5000/?a=2` )

my another question is, could be this kind of API host and request in something like Heroku?

Comment: I could get you an answer, but it is better for you and benefit you for long run to read the documentation about [Variable rules](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#variable-rules).

Answer (score 4):

From [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#routing):

> You can add variable sections to a URL by marking sections with `<variable_name>`. Your function then receives the `<variable_name>` as a keyword argument. Optionally, you can use a converter to specify the type of the argument like `<converter:variable_name>`.

So in your case that would be:

```
@app.route("/<int:a>")
def hello(a):
    return a + 2
```

Other option would be to use [request data](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#accessing-request-data).

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the parameter "a" in the decorator @app.route:

```
@app.route('/<int:a>')
def hello(a):
   return a + 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it like that, pass name as parameter !

```
@app.route('/helloworld/<Name>')
def helloworld(Name):
    print Name
```

another implementation would be like that, go through the python-flask documentation !

```
@app.route("/<int:a>")
def hello(a):
    return a + 2
```

Comment: thank you very much. yes, I should see the documentation. I did the second solution you said but I receive `The requested URL was not found on the server.`